# Update multiple rows dynamically SQL Stored Procedure

Tags: c#, sql, .net, web-services, stored-procedures

I have a Transaction Inventory table that contains (TIID, TID, catid, itemid, quantity, price, isdelete, entryNumber) Columns. I inserted Tow record's and the TID is default null. When I execute update stored procedure I want to update all TID null column with id that i have where TIID IN(@TIID).
[image]

**Table after record's inserted**
**Stored Procedure**

```
ALTER procedure [dbo].[UpdateTIID]
@TIID nvarchar(max),
@TID nvarchar(50)

as
begin
declare @sql nvarchar(max)
set @sql='Update TransactionInventory Set TID='+ @TID +'
          where TIID IN ('+ @TIID +') '
          print @sql
exec (@sql)
end
```

> C# Code
>   [image]

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (That SP code is product specific.)

Comment: Run the query in SQL Server Management Studio before running in c#.  The error messages are much better in SSMS and the error looks like is is in the stored procedure.

Comment: The query like this => UPDATE staff SET salary = 1200 WHERE name IN ('Bob', 
                                    'Frank', 'John');                                                                        but when i pass all id's through scaler variable (@TIID) then only 1 row updated, the @TIID have 2 id's separated with comma. I want to update all rows their id's = TIID.